# How to calculate the terminal velocity of grains in a pneumatic conveyor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, process-engineering, pneumatic, conveyor

Here is the main question I got from a textbook:

Rice is transported by a pneumatic conveyor. The particle density is 1.4g/cm³. The major, intermediate and minor diameters are 1cm, 0.3cm and 0.4cm respectively. The density of the moving air is 1.1g/cm³. The velocity of the air is 10m/s while the major diameter is 20cm. Calculate the terminal velocity of the grains and the power requirements of the system. Overall drag coefficient is 2.6 and pressure drop 22mm of water

I already know the formula to use in finding the terminal velocity but my challenge lies in how to find the mass or weight of the rice particle in order to proceed with this formular:

$$V_t = \left[\frac{2W(P_p-P_f)}{P_pP_fA_pC}\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$

Moreover, which is suitable for as equivalent diameter? Geometric or arithmetic?
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: measure the weight of a rice grain

Comment: You could weigh one grain of rice, as @jsotola suggests, or you could find the average mass of a grain of rice by accurately measuring the mass of a number of grains of rice & then dividing by the number of rice grains. Also will you be using long, short or medium grain rice? Their masses will be different.